# Difference between toArray() and json_decode() for Laravel Blade

Tags: json, laravel

When simply returning $users, I get the exact same result with toArray() and json_decode().
But when looping $users in my view, I get an error ('Trying to get property 'xxx' of non-object) with the toArray() method. Not with json_decode(). Any idea why? I'm on Laravel 6.

```
   $client = HttpClient::create();
   $response = $client->request('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
   $users = json_decode($response->getContent());
// $users = $response->toArray();
   return $users;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The toArray() method return pure array. While json_decode() keys are always strings, while the value can be a string, number, true or false, null or even an object or an array.

Therefore, you are trying to access an object returned by json_decode which works if you have objects while encoding it. But, while trying to access an object from array perspective it will not work because arrays are plain array.

Explanation of Json_decode()

> PHP's json_decode function takes a JSON string and converts it into a PHP variable. Typically, the JSON data will represent a JavaScript array or object literal which json_decode will convert into a PHP array or object.

Explaining PHP array is beyond this scope. However:

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates values to keys. This type is optimized for several different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack, queue, and probably more. As array values can be other arrays, trees and multidimensional arrays are also possible.

Finally, 
You are trying to access an object returned by json_decode - works fine. But an array will not hold objects such that it throws that trying to get property of non-object.

Comment: Very clear explanation, many thanks! This is the correct answer but unfortunately StackOverflow doesn't let me tag it as it :/

Comment: What do you mean by tag it as it

Comment: O no sorry it works ;-) I thought I needed 15 reputation to accept an answer as correct